# Application not loading - applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an iOS app that some customers are saying won't load, and they see a spinner indefinitely.  This spinner starts in the app delegate.

I was finally able to reproduce this if I put a breakpoint in the applicationDidBecomeActive delegate and then let xcode run.  There is an NSTimer being called in here.

I was wondering if this is something others have seen this, is there a conflict with this delegate and NSTimers?

EDIT: Code sample from memory.  I'll have to get the actual code here later.

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {    
  [self toggleOpen];    
}

- (void)toggleOpen {      
  if (!self.timer) {
      self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600 target:self selector:@selector(doWork) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  } else {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
  }
}
- (void)doWork {
  //Under certain conditions calls a web service (rarely)
}
```

Comment: Show some code and provide more details or no one will be able to help.

Comment: Yeah, add some code about your problem.

Comment: I tried your code and it does not block the interface. The `doWork` method gets called as expected. Probably the issue resides in the implementation of such method

Comment: Well, of course it'll appear to hang indefinitely if the app is suspended due to hitting a breakpoint.

Comment: It hits the breakpoint then let xcode run.  It will hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was regarding the NSTimer fired in the applicationDidBecomeActive.  This may have created an NSTimer before the run loop was available.  Commenting out the NSTimer to fire in the applicationDidBecomeActive seems to have fixed the app from never launching.

Answer (score 1):

If the app can not load at all and just shows the spinner since it starts, it can't be because of the timer, since it just schedules the `doWork` method to be fired 600 seconds after the app has become active, and then moves on to the next command.

However, if the app loads fine and then gets stuck in the `doWork` method after 600 seconds, it might be because of the way the web service is being called (synchronous vs asynchronous calls).

So, like the others have said, can't help much unless you show some more code.